# Multi-threaded core data sometimes returns nil properties

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, background-process

I am new to core data. I have an app that uses core data as local store. Writing to and reading from core data is done by background threads. While this works generally, in rare cases are the fetched data wrong, i.e. properties of a fetched entity are `nil`.
To check the situation, I wrote a unit test that starts 2 async threads: One fetches continuously from core data, and the other one overwrites continuously these data by first deleting all data, and then storing new data.
This test pretty quickly provokes the error, but I have no idea why. Of course I guess this is a multi-threading problem, but I don’t see why, because fetches and deletion+writes are done in separate managed contexts of a single `persistentContainer`.
I am sorry that the code below is pretty long, although shortened, but I think without it one cannot identify the problem.
Any help is highly welcome!

Here is my function to fetch data:

```
func fetchShoppingItems(completion: @escaping (Set<ShoppingItem>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedContext) in 
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDShoppingItem> = CDShoppingItem.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let cdShoppingItems: [CDShoppingItem] = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for nextCdShoppingItem in cdShoppingItems {
                nextCdShoppingItem.managedObjectContext!.performAndWait {
                    let nextname = nextCdShoppingItem.name! // Here, sometimes name is nil
                } // performAndWait
            } // for all cdShoppingItems
            completion(nil, nil)
            return
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // error handling
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        } // fetch error
    } // performBackgroundTask
} // fetchShoppingItems
```

I have commented the line that sometimes crashes the test, since `name` is `nil`.

Here are my functions to store data:

```
func overwriteCD(shoppingItems: Set<ShoppingItem>,completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedContext) in 
        self.deleteAllCDRecords(managedContext: managedContext, in: "CDShoppingItem")
        let cdShoppingItemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CDShoppingItem",in: managedContext)!
        for nextShoppingItem in shoppingItems {
            let nextCdShoppingItem = CDShoppingItem(entity: cdShoppingItemEntity,insertInto: managedContext)
            nextCdShoppingItem.name = nextShoppingItem.name
        } // for all shopping items
        self.saveManagedContext(managedContext: managedContext)
        completion()
    } // performBackgroundTask
} // overwriteCD  

func deleteAllCDRecords(managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext, in entity: String) {
    let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)
    deleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.execute(deleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
        let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
        let changes = [NSDeletedObjectsKey: objectIDArray]
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes as [AnyHashable: Any], into: [managedContext])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // error handling
    }
} // deleteAllCDRecords

func saveManagedContext(managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if !managedContext.hasChanges { return }
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // error handling
    }
} // saveManagedContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code was apparently a race condition:
While the „fetch“ thread fetched the core data records, and tried to assign the attributes to the properties, the „store“ thread deleted the records.
This apparently released the attribute objects, so that `nil` was stored as property.
I thought that the `persistentContainer` would automatically prevent this, but it does not.

The solution is to execute both background threads of the `persistentContainer` in a **concurrent serial queue**, the „fetch“ thread synchronously, and the „store“ thread asynchronously **with a barrier**.
So, concurrent fetches can be executed, while a store waits until all current fetches are finished.

The concurrent serial queue is defined as

```
let localStoreQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xxx.yyy.LocalStore.localStoreQueue", 
    attributes: .concurrent)
```

**EDIT:**
In the following fetch and store functions, I moved the core data function `persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask` inside the `localStoreQueue`. If it were outside as in my original answer, the store code in `localStoreQueue.async(flags: .barrier)` would setup a new thread and thus use `managedContext` in another thread that it was created in, which is a core data multi-threading error.

The „fetch“ thread is modified as

```
localStoreQueue.sync {
  self.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedContext) in
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDShoppingItem> = CDShoppingItem.fetchRequest()
    //…
  } // performBackgroundTask  
} // localStoreQueue.sync
```

and the „store“ thread as

```
localStoreQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
  self.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedContext) in
    self.deleteAllCDRecords(managedContext: managedContext, in: "CDShoppingItem")
    //…
  } // performBackgroundTask
} // localStoreQueue.async
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `name` isn't nil for all requested entities? Just use guard-let to avoid `!` for optional variables. Also `!` it isn't safe way to unwrap optional variable especially if you can't be sure for source of data.

Comment: When I store the `name` property, it is definitively not `nil` (the property is no optional). And this is the reason why I used the !. Otherwise, you are completely right.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, ok, but on crash what is nil? `name` or the entity? I think if `name` is nil you should look for errors in saving method, not reading. Also you can try to add default value on `nextCdShoppingItem.name = nextShoppingItem.name`, if nextShoppinItem.name is optional. ex: `nextCdShoppingItem.name = nextShoppingItem.name ?? ""`

Comment: The entity is not `nil`, but the property. Maybe I should modify the fetch function so that it fetches the entity a 2nd time in case of error. That would at least show if reading or writing fails.